# How to create a multilingual node programmatically?

Tags: nodes, 8, i18n-l10n

In the last days [I tried to migrate a multilingual CSV file to Drupal 8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/224099/28275) without success, so finally I decided to use a [Batch Process](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/224230/28275) to accomplish the task.

At this moment I have the batch process working, but at this point I need to create my nodes and create the translation. So, how to create a multilingual node programmatically?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Fortunately I found a post named [Create and translate a multilingual nodes programmatically.](http://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/50/create-and-translate-a-multilingual-nodes-programmatically)

And here is the code with some comments:

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

$node = Node::create([
  // The node entity bundle in this case article.
  'type' => 'article',
  //The base language
  'langcode' => 'en',
  'created' => \Drupal::time()->getRequestTime(),
  'changed' => \Drupal::time()->getRequestTime(),
  // The user ID.
  'uid' => 1,
  'title' => 'My test!',
  //If you have another field lets says field_day you can do this:
  //'field_day' => 'value',
  'body' => [
    'summary' => '',
    'value' => '<p>The body of my node.</p>',
    'format' => 'full_html',
  ],
]);
//Saving the node
$node->save();
//This line is not necessary
\Drupal::service('path.alias_storage')->save("/node/" . $node->id(), "/my/path", "en");

//Creating the translation Spanish in this case
$node_es = $node->addTranslation('es');
$node_es->title = 'Mi prueba!';
$node_es->body->value = '<p>El cuerpo de mi nodo.</p>';
$node_es->body->format = 'full_html';
//Saving the node
$node_es->save();
//This line is not necessary
\Drupal::service('path.alias_storage')->save("/node/" . $node->id(), "/mi/ruta", "es");
```

Comment: I get the following error : InvalidArgumentException : Invalid translation language (en) specified. dans Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase->addTranslation() (ligne 863 de /.../Core/Entity/ContentEntityBase.php).

Comment: @Pauloscorps – You have to ensure the `en` language exists or maybe ensure the config that adds the `en` language got imported successfully **before** running Adrian's code.

Answer (score 4):

I was racking my brain over this problem in Drupal 8. Here's how I finally got it done, This code copies title, body, all fields, and the pathauto setting. I'm sure there's room for improvement here as some meta fields probably need to get processed too. But this should get you started!

```
// This assumes you have a $node variable that contains the node translation you're starting with
$node_trans = $node->addTranslation('en-au'); // sample using Australian English
$node_trans->setTitle($node->getTitle());
$node_trans_fields = $node->getTranslatableFields();
foreach ($node_trans_fields as $name => $field) {
  if (substr($name, 0, 6) == 'field_' || in_array($name, ['body', 'path', 'title'])) {
    $node_trans->set($name, $field->getValue());
  }
}
try {
  $node->save();
}
catch (\Exception $error) {
  $add_status .= 'ERROR saving ';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The last part of Adrian's answer didn't work for me.

For the translation part, use:

```
$node->addTranslation('es', ['title' => "Translate title"])->save();
```

Comment: Hi Tib, is weird, I copy the code from a working example that I have in a project.

Comment: Hi, I'm on Drupal 8.4.2 maybe they changed something in the core. I don't remember the exact error but it was about the title field.