# Add an existing node as a translation to another node

Tags: 8, nodes

I am migrating contents from a multilingual website. I'm using Feed modules to import all the nodes so, in the end, I have multiple nodes that are in English and multiple nodes that are in French. Then, i wrote a DRUSH command where I have a CSV file that contains URL Alias of both slug of English and French. I can then process that info and get the node ID of both related Node.

But I just can't see how I can't tell drupal to attach an existing node (FR) as a translation of another node (EN). Does anyone has ever wanted to do something similar?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems there are some patches you can test, but further help is necessary to implement multilingual Feeds import for D8, chip in if you can: [Add translation to node in feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds/issues/3008340)

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/276302/15055 in particular shows how to add a translation to an existing node. You can abstract this quite easy to then feed it the values of another existing node.